# Typo3 v.8.7 - cannot set anchor links

Tags: menu, typo3, anchor

I would like to set an anchor link in the main navigation. I think I have changed some relevant settings - now the anchors do not appear in the link selection window.

[image]

"Über uns" is a shortcut to "/home". This is fine, but I would like to link to /home#c123 which is a certain section on the home page.

You can see in my screenshot above: there are no elements of "Home" displayed in the link selection. Do I have to enable some kind of feature for that?

I have already tried / verified:

- The target element on the /home page has "Show in Section Menus"
  enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking to sections on pages is not possible for shortcut targets, only linking to pages.

You could [add a custom page type](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/PageTypes/#create-new-page-type) with a custom field for this which then needs to be outputted accordingly in your navigation code.

Comment: Thank you! Typo3 is full of surprises.